# Siemens S5 to S7 XR.INI file

Tags: plc, s5

I'm trying to convert a program from S5 to S7. I've taken a look into the tutorials and documents that are available. But I cant seem to find any information about this problem:

The program is pretty complicated and I should need the XR.INI file to convert it with the S5 Converter program that came with Simatic S7. When I open the folder with the project I see all the files I need and that are described in the tutorial made by Siemens.

.ST.S5D
.XR.INI
.Z0.SEQ

I start the converter and open .ST.S5D. When I did this I get the error there is no .XR.INI file. But I can see it in the folder. Its called CERMST.INI. So I guess the name isnt correct?

In PG2000 I remade the XRF with CTRL Q but nothing changed. I also tried to rename the file to CERM.XR.INI because I saw somewhere these files can only be 6 characters long (not sure if this is true).

I tried first without the XRF. There were some errors because of the ASM command. In the tutorial I saw the converter cant handle these so I removed these functions from the program to rewrite manually later on. After this I had an error because I had no XRF. Error was:

Error No PLC type description found for called or addressed block

So I really need the .XR.INI file but the program can't find it, but its clearly in the folder. How can I fix this? How can I make a new .INI file?

Link to tutorial: http://www.sankotek.com/TR/Dokumanlar/STEP%207%20-%20From%20S5%20to%20S7.pdf

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siemens S5 file extensions used also last two letters before file extension to mark file type, like xxxxxxXX.XXX where x is file name and X is file type for S5, without second dot in the middle like you have. File name length limit exists, I think it comes from DOS or some older operating system file length limit.

If you don't have XRF file then if i remember correctly compiler does not have compile order. Some blocks have not been compiled but are referenced in caller block that the compiler tries to compile. Compiler does not find called block in compiled blocks folder and wham... fatal error. When i had such troubles i compiled called blocks independenly before calling blocks. So you can do without XRF file. But try to include Z0.SEQ, that file has assignment list so you get nice variable names instead of just variable address numbers.

Also, stackoverflow is not the correct place to ask questions about Siemens S5-S7 conversion. You should post your questions in http://www.plctalk.net, they have guys there who used to program S5 plc-s.